# Error handing in JSON value (not the actual AJAX request)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, http-status-code-404

Background - I'm calling a JSON feed via jQuery's AJAX method. No issues here. One of the values in the feed points to an image URL on Instagram and I then render the image in html.

Here's the problem - most of the Instagram URLs come back fine and the image renders on my html page as expected but a couple of URLs return 404 errors and therefore render no image.

My question - is there a way to check for that 404 error and tell the code to do something else?

Code -

```
var $SS__image = j.mainasset;

$output += '<img src="' + $SS__image + '" />';
```

What I want to achieve -

```
var $SS__image = j.mainasset;

if($SS__image.ERROR === '404'){
    $output = '';
}else{
    $output = '<img src="' + $SS__image + '" />';
}
```

Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
var $img = $("<img/>"); 
$img.on("error",function() {
  $(this).remove();
});
$output.append($img);
$img.attr("src",$SS__image); // in this order
```